# Swap largest and last elements in array

Tags: java, arrays, swap

I am trying to swap the largest element in an array with the last element in an array.

So far I have been able to place the largest element into the last element slot but am unable to swap the last element into the largest element slot.

```java
int largest = arr[0];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > largest) {
        largest = arr[i];

        //swap largest with last
        temp = largest;
        int last = arr.length;
        arr[last - 1] = largest;
        temp = arr[last - 1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest you break down your code into separate functions which can be tested independently and most likely will have other uses.  For example...

```
void swap(int ar[], int i, int j) {
    int t = ar[i];
    ar[i] = ar[j];
    ar[j] = t;
}

int findMaxIndex(int ar[]) {
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {    
        if (ar[i] > ar[maxIndex])  maxIndex = i; 
    }
    return maxIndex;
}

...
int arr[] ...
int maxIndex = findMaxIndex(arr);
swap(arr,maxIndex,length(arr)-1);
```

Note that there is no error handling to keep the code brief.  This will fix not so subtle bug in your logic as well.  For example if start with the array

```
1,2,3,4
```

you'll end up with

```
1,4,2,3
```